# Python - Sort list in descending order - Type Error

Tags: python-3.x, sorting

## iPod Game Guesser - Leaderboard Feature

```
    leaderboard = open("Score.txt", "a+")
    score = str(score)
    leaderboard.write(Username + ' : ' + score + '\n')
    leaderboard.close()

    leaderboard = open("Score.txt", "r")
    Scorelist = leaderboard.readlines()
    scores = {}
    for row in Scorelist:
        user, score = row.split(':')
        scores[user] = int(score)
        highest_ranking_users = sorted(scores, key=lambda x: scores[x], reverse=True)
    for user in highest_ranking_users:
        print (f'{user} : {score[user]}')
```

---

So this is the game I have done for my GCSE OCR Project, somehow I am getting errors for the last line of my code. \\print (f'{user} : {score[user]}')\\, the error it displays as follows:

TypeError: string indices must be integers

Please help! Any comments will be appreciated!

Comment: Player1 : 9
Player2 : 6
Player3 : 7
Player4 : 8

Comment: This is what the raw data looks like (In a .txt file)

Comment: Did you mean to write `{scores[user]}` instead of `{score[user]}`? Note that you have both `score` and `scores` as variable names.

Comment: Oh, I just changed print (f'{user} : {score[user]}') to:

Comment: print (f'{user} : {scores[user]}') and now it works, looks like I have made a sily mistake whilist typing, thank you so much for spotting it out!

Comment: Much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using dict type and sorted is for the list, not dict. In order to sort a dict, you have to use a list and make a dict again or just use the list to print the highest score list.

```
score = {'Player1' : 9, 'Player2' : 6, 'Player3' : 7, 'Player4' : 8}
sorted_score = sorted(score.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

for score in sorted_score:
    print('{} : {}'.format(score[0], score[1]))
```

This gives the result,

```
Player1 : 9
Player4 : 8
Player3 : 7
Player2 : 6
```

---

You can adapt my code, i.e.

```
with open("test.txt", "r") as file:
    scores = []
    for row in file.read().splitlines():
        scores.append(row.split(' : '))

sorted_score = sorted(scores, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

for score in sorted_score:
    print('{} : {}'.format(score[0], score[1]))
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, but the objective is to extract a list from external file and sort it. Is there any other ways to achieve this?

Comment: What is the problem so far?

Comment: I see what you mean here, now I just have to get the code indented. Sorry for late replying

Comment: I managed to run the code you sent me, it displays the leaderboard but not in the order of descending scores.

Comment: I have revised your comment above, it solved my problem, thank you so much for helping!